# Using Selenium Webdriver, how do I verify the contents/data in the sheets of an excel file that was launched from a page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can Selenium Webdriver detect the excel file in the first place?

Comment: Selenium does not handle the Excel, it is handled by the language you are using selenium with.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Webdriver Library doesn't handle the Excel files,You need to use the external library  to handle the excel file. There are two famous libraries, which you can use, one is Apache POI  library, you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoi30FINALjar.htm). The other one JXL java library,download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxl2612jar.htm).Before starting work with any of this library, there is main difference between this two library is JXL handle only the files which is having the .xls extention(Microsoft Excel 2003-2007 File), whereas Apache POI can handle .xls as well as .xlsx(Microsoft Excel 2010 File). So my suggestion is you should go for Apache POI.

Answer (score 0):

selenium can not handle excel sheets.
excel sheet is not a part of application , data is loaded into the excel sheet and operating system will open the file.

once excel file opened use Apache POI/Jexcel to validate the content.